# Prevent cssMin from removing svg styles

Tags: css, svg, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-cssmin

When running the grunt.js task cssMin 
https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-cssmin

Svg css properties are being removed.

For example:

```
.testClass {
   r: 4;
   width: 3px;
   margin-left: 18px !important;
}
```

Gets converted to

```
.testClass {
   width: 3px;
   margin-left: 18px !important;
}
```

How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>`grunt-contrib-cssmin` uses [`clean-css`](https://github.com/jakubpawlowicz/clean-css) internally, as stated in [options](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-cssmin#options), and any native (`clean-css`) options *"are passed to clean-css"*.</strike>

`clean-css` groups optimizations into [levels](https://github.com/jakubpawlowicz/clean-css#optimization-levels), for convenience. There are two options controlling removal of rules, both found under level 2:

```
restructureRules: false, // should disable all removals
skipProperties: []       // specify individual rules to skip
```

This should do it:

```
cssmin: {
  options: {
    skipProperties: ['r']
  }
}
```

---

Starting with clean-css [4.2.0](https://github.com/jakubpawlowicz/clean-css#whats-new-in-version-42) a "comment" block method for skipping fragments entirely will be available:

```
/* clean-css ignore:start */
.testClass {
   r: 4;
   width: 3px;
   margin-left: 18px !important;
}
/* clean-css ignore:end */
```

Note `4.2` has not been released yet.

---

**After a bit of testing, none of the above seems to actually work, although they "should", according to documentation.**
The only alternative I have is replacing `grunt-contrib-cssmin` with `grunt-postcss cssnano` (which is what I use with grunt for minification):

```
npm install grunt-postcss cssnano
```

```js
grunt.initConfig({
  postcss: {
    processors: [
      require('cssnano')({
        // options here...
      })
    ]
  },
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-postcss');
grunt.registerTask('postcss', ["postcss"]);
```

In practice, I use more `postcss` addons.
Here's a practical example with `autoprefixer`, `pixrem`, `postcss-flexbox` and `cssnano`:

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        postcss: {
            options: {
                processors: [
                    require('pixrem'),
                    require('autoprefixer')({browsers: ['> 0%']}),
                    require('postcss-flexboxfixer'),
                    require('cssnano')({
                      autoprefixer:false,
                      zindex: false
                    })
                ]
            },
            jack: {
                files: [{
                    expand:true,
                    flatten:true,
                    cwd: 'assets/',
                    src: ['scss/*.css', '!**/variables.css'],
                    dest:'assets/css/'
                }]
            }
        },
        watch: {
            styles: {
                files: [
                    'assets/scss/*.css'
                ],
                tasks:['postcss:jack']
            }
        }
    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-postcss');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.registerTask('default', ["watch:styles"]);
    grunt.registerTask('jack', ["postcss:jack"]);
};
```

I purposefully registered a task that only runs the `postcss` plugin:

```
grunt jack
```

Don't forget you need to install each addon for usage with `postcss`. For the above, you'd need:

```
npm install grunt-postcss cssnano pixrem autoprefixer postcss-flexboxfixer
```

... and, most likely, you'll want to change `files` to match whatever you have.

This time around, I tested. The `r` property makes it into the minified file:

```
.testClass{r:20;width:3px;margin-left:18px!important}
```

Comment: This doesn't work.  I have tried adding the skipProperties: ['r'] in my options, but the error still comes up "Invalid property name 'r' at test.css:2:3. Ignoring." and the resulting file doesn't contain the r property.

Comment: @Jack, I updated my answer with an alternative solution. Let me know if it was of any use.

Comment: Thanks Andrei.   I tested this and it indeed works as expected.  Thanks so much for your time and thought into this answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to prevent this by setting restructuring to false in the options:

```
options: {
  restructuring: false
},
```

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to work either.  The property is still showing up.